# MongoDB c# driver: Case Insensitive Compare using in or contains on a list using linq

Tags: c#, linq, mongodb

I am using the MongoDB C# driver and I want to do a linq where clause on the collection that compares the lower cased version of a property to the lower case version of a list I have in memory. like this;

```
items = items.Where(i => listToCheck.Contains(i.Property.ToLower()));
```

I have also tried...

```
items = items.Where(i => i.Property.ToLower().In(listToCheck));
```

I think that this is actually correct and should work but possibly hasn't been implemented.

I get an error saying 'Unsupported where clause' relating to the ToLower() command. From what I can see the driver currently can't accomplish this because it would have to do an 'IN' query with Regex which I can't see being possible.

What I would like to know is if it is possible and if so, how?

Comment: Did you try: `items = items.Where(i => listToCheck.Any(item => item.ToLower() == i.Property.ToLower()));`?

Comment: i just tried it and it didnt work. i got this error...
'Unable to determine the serialization information for the expression: String[]:{ "one", "two" }'

Comment: is items queryable? it could be you need to do items.AsQueryable()

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I eventually found a solution to this issue, after a lot of digging I found that the `toLower()` methods are not implemented in the mongoDb linq provider so i had to change to using MongoQuery

I created some extension methods for string and list where it takes the string or list as a source and converts it to a bson regular expression

```
internal static List<BsonValue> ConvertToCaseInsensitiveRegexList(this IEnumerable<string> source)
{
    return source.Select(range => new BsonRegularExpression("/^" + range.Replace("+", @"\+") + "$/i")).Cast<BsonValue>().ToList();
}

internal static List<BsonValue> ConvertToEndsWithRegexList(this IEnumerable<string> source)
{
    return source.Select(range => new BsonRegularExpression("/" + range.Replace("+", @"\+") + "$/i")).Cast<BsonValue>().ToList();
}

internal static BsonRegularExpression ToCaseInsensitiveRegex(this string source)
{
    return new BsonRegularExpression("/^" + source.Replace("+", @"\+") + "$/i");
}
```

and then they are used like this...

```
var colours = new List<string> { "Red", "blue", "white" };
var query = Query<myObject>.In(v => v.Colour, colours.ConvertToCaseInsensitiveRegexList());
this.Find(query).ToList();
```

Comment: var match = theCollection.AsQueryable().SingleOrDefault(x =>
    x.Email.ToLower() == emailToSearchFor.ToLower()); from https://stackoverflow.com/a/40886169/2069306

Answer (score 3):

I ran across this same problem, and had to piece together a solution from several different SO answers, including this one.

I was already using IQueryable everywhere in the solution, along with a repository pattern, so I really didn't want to drop back to using `.Find()`

My solution was to extend the filter definition builder with a three-parameter `.In()` overload which would provide case insensitivity. Then, I use `.Where(_ => filter.Inject())` to add the filter to the query, while still keeping it as IQueryable.

The extension:

```
public static class MongoExtensions
{
    public static FilterDefinition<TDocument> In<TDocument>(
        this FilterDefinitionBuilder<TDocument> builder,
        Expression<Func<TDocument, object>> expr,
        IEnumerable<string> values,
        bool ignoreCase)
    {
        if (!ignoreCase)
        {
            return builder.In(expr, values);
        }

        var filters = values
            .Select(v => builder.Regex(expr, new BsonRegularExpression($"^{Regex.Escape(v)}$", "i")));

        return builder.Or(filters);
    }
}
```

With the original code from the question, it would look something like:

```
var filter = Builders<MyCollection>.Filter.In(i => i.Property, listToCheck, true);
items = items.Where(_ => filter.Inject());
```