# Mongo c# driver, linq-to-mongo: find all records with a field value which a specific string starts from

Tags: mongodb, linq, mongodb-query, mongodb-.net-driver

Say, we have the following docs (other fields are omitted for simplicity):

```
{ _id: 1, name: 'a' }
{ _id: 2, name: 'ab' }
{ _id: 3, name: 'abc' }
{ _id: 4, name: 'acde' }
{ _id: 5, name: 'b' }
```

I'm just wondering if it's possible to translate the following linq to the mongodb query:

```
_collection.AsQueryable().Where(m => "abcdef".StartsWith(m.name));
```

I'm expecting to get the following output:

```
{ _id: 1, name: 'a' }
{ _id: 2, name: 'ab' }
{ _id: 3, name: 'abc' }
{ _id: 4, name: 'acde' }
```

But I get an error: "Unsupported filter: \"abcdef\".StartsWith({document}{name})."

Does mongo querying system support some appropriate alternative for that? How should I re-write my query? Or the only way is to retrieve all docs from mongo and then filter them in .net application?

Answer (score 0):

You may find this answer useful. It uses regex for the string comparison.

[MongoDB c# driver: Case Insensitive Compare using in or contains on a list using linq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25745276/mongodb-c-sharp-driver-case-insensitive-compare-using-in-or-contains-on-a-list)